# Please explain this output of the code

Tags: c, function, return, printf, scanf

```
#include<stdio.h>
int GetPositiveInt(void);

int main(void)
{
    int num = GetPositiveInt();
    printf("%d",num);
    return 0;
}

int GetPositiveInt(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a positive number : ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }while(n<=0);

}
```

The output is the value of `n` but I don't know how it is returned to `num`.
Does `scanf()` and `printf()` affect the `return` value of a function?

If I add a statement like `printf("%d",7)`; after `while` then the output is `71`,no idea how `1` comes.

[This is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1R8d5.jpg) my output. This is for reference only .

Text as requested :-

> usr@usr:~/C_programs$ gcc -std=c99 return.c -o return
>
> usr@usr:~/C_programs$ ./return
>
> Enter a positive number : 45
>
> 45usr@usr:~/C_programs$ ./return
>
> Enter a positive number : 89
>
> 89usr@usr:~/C_programs$

Comment: The code you posted does not even compile. It needs a semicolon after the declaration of function `GetPositiveInt()` (line 2) and a `return n;` statement after the `while` line.

Comment: Sorry for the ; in declaration. But for the return n; part , my initial question is that i am getting the value of 'n' in 'num' even without using a return statement.The output of this code prints the value of ,n' I entered for me

Comment: I cannot see the image of your o/p. Please post it as text.

Comment: The output is only for the refrence of others who stumble upon the question.The auto correct changed it to "Kindly explain this " earlier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the following function:

```
int GetPositiveInt(void)
{
  int n;
  do
  {
    printf("Enter a positive number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  }while(n<=0);

}
```

the function is expected to `return` an `int` value, whereas there is no `return` statement. You probably wanted to return the value of `n`. This can be achieved by adding the suitable `return` statement:

```
 return n;
```

Like this:

```
int GetPositiveInt(void)
{
  int n;
  do
  {
    printf("Enter a positive number : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
  }while(n<=0);

  return n;
}
```

Comment: main should return 0 if not value is specified i think,but why my code works even without return n; GetPositiveInt() is returning value of 'n' even without the return statement for me

Comment: It does not return, those are garbage values. And about main, yes you are right, though it's common practice.

Comment: thats a bit enlightening,the same code gives me a different output,any reason why?

Comment: @abhishekjaiswal , Other answers have said that your code exhibits Undefined Behavior. And Undefined Behavior means that **anything** can happen. Your code might give expected or unexpected results. You should avoid UB as much as possible.

Comment: The behaviour is undefined: In ideone the output was 1, on my compiler, the output is 0.

Comment: @karma_geek , Please format and indent your code correctly when posting an answer.

Comment: @CoolGuy: I tried to do that, but for some reason it wasn't getting highlighted. I tried 4 spaces and enter etc.

Comment: You need 8 spaces for formatting as code in lists. See my edit

Comment: i added my output in the question just for a refrence but i guess the particular output i am getting is somewhat related to the compiler.i guess its better to just stick to the rules

Comment: It is undefined, output could be anything

Answer (score 4):

> **TL;DR** Your code produces undeifined behavior.

You're missing a `return` statement in `GetPositiveInt()` function. Without having an explicit `return` statement to return a value, collecting the return value of the function call in the caller function and using that leads to [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Ref: As per the `C11` standard document, chapter §6.9.1,

> If the `}` that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

---

FWIW, only in case of `main()` , addition of `return` statement is ***not mandatory***. From same document, chapter 5.1.2.2.3, for `main()` function

> reaching the `}` that terminates the main function returns a value of 0.

Answer (score 2):

> no idea how '1' comes.

Because you did not return anything in your method `GetPositiveInt` - and the behavior is undefined:

```
int GetPositiveInt(void)
{
    int n;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter a positive number : ");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }while(n<=0);

    return n; //<---Add this line

}
```

C99 6.9.1/12 "Function definitions" says:

> If the } that terminates a function is reached, and the value of the function call is used by the caller, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

It prints `0` for me.

As explained in the other answers, the lack of the `return` statement in a function that is declared to return something is signaled by the compiler with a warning but the generated code exposes undefined behaviour. This means the function can return any value, the compiler cannot guarantee anything about it.

You can think of the value returned by a function as a hidden local variable of that function. Since the `return` statement is missing, the hidden variable is not initialized and its value is whatever garbage data happened to be in the memory at the time when the function was called.

In practice, the `return` statement is translated into a processor instruction that copies the returned value into one of the general-purpose processor's registries (usually `%eax` on `x86`). The calling function (`main()` in your code) gets the values from that register and uses it.

Because your function `GetPositiveInt()` does not contain a `return` statement, the compiler skips generating the instruction that puts the correct value in `%eax` and the function completes its execution letting in `%eax` whatever value happened to be there as a result of earlier processing.

Answer (score 0):

This is a case of undefined behaviour because you are missing the return statement.however I can explain why 1 is coming.

The printf function returns the number of characters printed by it.For example

```
 printf("%d",printf("%d",7));
```

first printf prints 7 and returns 1 as number of characters printed. So output is 71.

Comment: The OP never used `printf("%d",printf("%d",7));`

Comment: @Cool Guy I never said that, I only wrote that to explain that printf returns the number of characters printed